# How do i fetch the IP address from the following tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, tuples

```py
('table',
 [(1,
   {u'Node': u'1',
    u'Mode': u'a',
    u'HostName': u'hn19',
    u'Address': u'10.10.10.10'}),
   (2,
    {u'Node': u'2',
     u'Mode': u'b',
     u'HostName': u'hn20',
     u'Address': u'10.10.10.11'})])
```

Please suggest some ways to avoid loops.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can just index it? And if there are multiple records, you obviously have to iterate over it;

Comment: @Aditya i don't want to hard code it

Comment: Please show what have you tried in python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
_, table = that_data_you_posted
ip_addresses = [d[u'Address'] for _, d in table]
```

This just hides the loop in a list comprehension. There's obviously no way to avoid iterating over multiple rows in a table.

Comment: this is very useful, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a small tuple, we can continue with using index, but when you have a larger tuple, you'll surely have to use loops.

For now you may try this

```
#a is your tuple.
ipaddress1 = a[1][0][1][u'Address']
ipaddress2 = a[1][1][1][u'Address']
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

i would have created dict of key as host, values ip.

```
_, lst = tpl
ip_dict= { d[u'hn20'] : d[u'Address'] for _,d if u'hn20' in d and u'Address' in d }
```

the if condition is important because there are possibilities this key missing in dict.